# Snowflake stored procedure - sql - binding variables in the from clause

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please help in binding the stored procedure argument into the sql statement given

```
create or replace procedure test(table_name varchar)
returns integer
language sql
as
$$
 select count(*) from ?
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an [OBJECT INDENTIFIER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-snowflake-scripting.html#using-an-argument-as-an-object-identifier)

```
create or replace procedure test(table_name varchar)
returns integer
language sql
as
declare
  c number;
begin
  select count(*) into c from identifier(:table_name);

  return c;
end;
```

```
call test('test.test.testo');
```

| TEST |
| --- |
| 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Using [TABLE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/literals-table.html):

```
create or replace procedure test(table_name varchar)
returns integer
language sql
as
declare
  c number;
begin
  select count(*) into c from table(:table_name);

  return c;
end;

CALL test('tab');
-- 0
```